# run a process in another terminal

Tags: python, subprocess, signals, xterm

I'm actually running a subprocess from a python program using Popen

`proc= subprocess.Popen("xterm -e python script.py", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`

And when this process is running on xterm, we can kill it using `Ctrl+C`, is there a way to send other signals using (`Ctrl+Z` and `fg`,...) to resume and continue the job?
Another solution would be running this process in another terminal, without using `xterm -e` is this possible?
Any other solution would be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do it programatically in [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/)

```
import psutil
p = psutil.Pocesss(proc.pid)
p.suspend()
p.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python2.6+

```
# send ctrl+c
popen.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

Comment: Thanks, but what should I do to make the proses react to the keyboard events? I found out that we can capture the different key press events with PyQt4 but I don't know how to use it, same comment to @highBandWidt